# how to change table name dynamically when joining stored procedure run

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic

I want to make a sql stored procedure and use it as the datasource of crystal report. i made it as follows and it works fine as i want.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ScanPointPrint]


 @branch varchar(50),
 @tripID int,
 @scanPoint varchar(50)

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
select sp.BranchCode, sp.ScanPoint, sp.TripId, sp.DoneBy,FORMAT(sp.DateTime,'dd MMMM, yyyy hh:mm tt'), sp.Driver, sp.CarNo, sp.ItemShouldBe, sp.ActualTaken, sp.MissedAny, sp.MissedCount, sp.TookExtra, sp.ExtraCount, spT.OrderNo,spt.ItemBarcode, oi.ItemName 
from ScanPointLog as sp
left join TableScanPoint1 as spT on sp.BranchCode = spT.BranchCode and sp.TripId = spT.TripId 
left join OrderItem as Oi on spt.OrderNo=oi.OrderNO and spt.ItemBarcode=oi.ItemBarcode
where sp.BranchCode=@branch and sp.ScanPoint=@scanPoint and spt.IsItem=1 and sp.TripId=@tripID

END

GO
```

what I want to perform and i am unable to do is changing the `TableScanPoint1` table name to another table name. there are 8 tables as TableScanPoint1 to TableScanePont8 with same structure but different data in them. the purpose to do this make one report design use it as the end user wants. the end user will choose table, branch, tripid and scanpoint from vb.net application at run time.

can anyone please help me on this ? 
thanks

Comment: Sounds like a broken data model. What is the relevance of the `1` - `8` values? Usually, this is in fact *data* but it has mistakenly been modelled as *metadata* (table names). You're now encountering difficulties writing queries because you need to query this data but it's not available as data.

Comment: I.e. this should be a single table with an additional column to store the `1` - `8` values and all of the data currently distributed between these 8 tables. Your query would then be trivial to create.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ScanPointPrint]


 @branch varchar(50),
 @tripID int,
 @scanPoint varchar(50),
 @tablenametoscan varchar(200)

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @sqltoexecute varchar(max)
set @sqltoexecute = '
select sp.BranchCode, sp.ScanPoint, sp.TripId, sp.DoneBy,FORMAT(sp.DateTime,'dd MMMM, yyyy hh:mm tt'), sp.Driver, sp.CarNo, sp.ItemShouldBe, sp.ActualTaken, sp.MissedAny, sp.MissedCount, sp.TookExtra, sp.ExtraCount, spT.OrderNo,spt.ItemBarcode, oi.ItemName 
from ScanPointLog as sp
left join ' +  @tablenametoscan + ' as spT on sp.BranchCode = spT.BranchCode and sp.TripId = spT.TripId 
left join OrderItem as Oi on spt.OrderNo=oi.OrderNO and spt.ItemBarcode=oi.ItemBarcode
where sp.BranchCode=@branch and sp.ScanPoint=@scanPoint and spt.IsItem=1 and sp.TripId=@tripID '


exec sp_executesql @sqltoexecute 
END

GO
```

Comment: though this create the stored procedure. it can't be connected with the crystal report. I changed the @sqltoexecute  varchar(max0 to nvarchar(MAX). then it was connected but I can't see any columns for the crystal report.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to make use of below query:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ScanPointPrint]

     @branch VARCHAR(50),
     @tripID INT,
     @scanPoint VARCHAR(50),
     @table VARCHAR(100)

    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(max)
    SET @query = '
    select sp.BranchCode, sp.ScanPoint, sp.TripId, sp.DoneBy,FORMAT(sp.DateTime,''dd MMMM, yyyy hh:mm tt''), sp.Driver, sp.CarNo, sp.ItemShouldBe, sp.ActualTaken, sp.MissedAny, sp.MissedCount, sp.TookExtra, sp.ExtraCount, spT.OrderNo,spt.ItemBarcode, oi.ItemName 
    from ScanPointLog as sp
    left join ' +  @table + ' as spT on sp.BranchCode = spT.BranchCode and sp.TripId = spT.TripId 
    left join OrderItem as Oi on spt.OrderNo=oi.OrderNO and spt.ItemBarcode=oi.ItemBarcode
    where sp.BranchCode=@branch and sp.ScanPoint=@scanPoint and spt.IsItem=1 and sp.TripId=@tripID '


    EXEC (@query) 
    END

    GO
```

Comment: the stored procedure created successfully with your code. but I can't see any column Fields in the crystal report :(

Comment: Did the pass the additional variable "@table" while calling the SP ?

Comment: Thanks praveen for supporting me. but I just skip this and made 8 store procedures and made 8 crystal reports. I know that sounds may silly but I am in hurry to finish my project.